# get us underway

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

I'm wondering why the word "us" is added in this sentence? I usually only say "get underway". Does this also apply with other verbs to add "us?" For example: Rashford scores **us** a beauty. Arsenal got **us** off to a flyer.

> Kick off! Manchester United get **us** under way.

Answer (score 1):

> They got under way

means that they got **themselves** going

> They got us under way

means that they got **us** going

In the first instance, we have an ellipsis where the reflexive direct object is omitted because it is understood implicitly. This kind of ellipsis is not very common.

Other of your examples would be called datives in languages with a fully developed system of cases. A dative indicates for whom or to whom an action was directed.

> He gave me the money

means

> He gave the money **to** me

Likewise,

> Rashford scores us a beauty

means

> Rashford scores a beauty **for** us

It would depend on context to know whether “for us” meant “for the pleasure of us viewers” or “for the benefit of our side.”

Comment: Without "us", is it still correct? Man Utd get underway.

Comment: Not quite. “Manchester United get**s** under way” is correct.  But it does not have the same meaning as “MU gets **us** under way,” which presumably means gets the audience started on enjoying the game.  “MU gets under way” means “MU gets itself started in playing the game.” Slightly different meanings. By the way, people who deal with sports, fashion, or entertainment frequently use rather unusual or trendy language to disguise the lack of substance in what they are babbling about.

Answer (score 0):

Without further context, it sounds like this is a quote from a commentator at a match. Therefore **us** refers to the spectators and particularly the MU fans present.
The commentator uses **us** to include himself with the fans and create an air of camaraderie.

Comment: Does "us" mean "them" in this context? I most often hear the comnentator use "us" when the game kicks off. Another example: Chelsea get us underway.

Comment: I think it means that it gets our collective experience of the game underway.